# How to get values of a ajax response

Tags: javascript, ajax

In my Javascript file, I get datas from server with an Ajax call :

```
this.$http.get("/data?startDate="+this.filtres.startDate+" "+this.filtres.startHour+"&endDate="+this.filtres.endDate+" "+this.filtres.endHour).then(function(response) {
    this.todos = response.body;
    this.$forceUpdate();
});
```

response.body looks like this :
[image]

```
(1) [...]
    0: Object { nbPieces: Getter & Setter, TRE: Getter & Setter, TRS: Getter & Setter, ... }
    __ob__: {…}
​        dep: Object { id: 35, subs: [] }​​
        value: Array [ {…} ]
        vmCount: 0​​
    <prototype>: Object { walk: walk(), observeArray: observeArray(), … }
    length: 1
```

Now I would like to put value of nbPieces, TRE and TRS into variables. I tried by doing `response.body.values()` but I doesn't work.

Comment: Can you post your response, i think responnse.body is an array !!

Comment: Please post the output of `console.log(response.body)`. The current output is totally unreadable. It looks like an array but I'm not sure because it's not clear now. If it's an array, then is it always going to have length of 1? If so, then something like this could help: `const [{ nbPieces, TRE, TRS }] = response.body`, and then you have your values in the variables with the same names

Comment: I just post it, indeed it's an array. Thank you for your comments !

Comment: @MissKnacki Please post the expanded output. Currently, it's hard to tell anything more than it's an array and it has an object inside. Please click the grey arrow there and post the result. Also, don't take screenshots of this, just copy-paste the text. It will be easier to operate on this while answering

Comment: Just edit my question @Sebastian Kaczmarek

Comment: Try with this: `const [{ nbPieces, TRE, TRS }] = response.body`

Comment: I works well, thank you !

Comment: Glad I could help. Posted as an answer then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `response.body` is an array with an object. If it's always going to have length of 1 then this will work for you:

```
const [{ nbPieces, TRE, TRS }] = response.body;
```

and then you can use it like normal variables:

```
console.log(nbPieces, TRE, TRS);
```